# socket.io-client with nginx -- fails with 404 for POST's! Why?

Tags: nginx, socket.io

I have an app that works fine on my development machine, but when it is moved to my nginx server is see:

```
0|app      | ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - POST /socket.io-client/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LwCov_4 HTTP/1.1 404 157 - 0.344 ms
0|app      | POST /socket.io-client/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LwCov_4 404 0.344 ms - 157
0|app      | ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - GET /socket.io-client/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LwCowC_ HTTP/1.1 200 - - 1.045 ms
0|app      | GET /socket.io-client/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LwCowC_ 200 1.045 ms - -
```

where ALL GET's succeed and ALL POST's fail with 404.

The relevant part of the nginx config is:

```
location / {
   proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header   Host      $host;
   proxy_pass https://localhost:9000;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
   proxy_redirect https://xxxx.com:9000/ https://xxxx.com/;
}

location ~* \.io  {
   proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

   proxy_pass https://localhost:9000;
   proxy_redirect off;

   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
 }
```

The express piece has:

```
import { handleSocket } from './config/socketio';

let server = https.createServer(options, app);

let socketio = socket_io(server, {
   serveClient: localEnv.env !== 'production',
   path: '/socket.io'
});

server.listen(localEnv.port, () => {
   log('Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', localEnv.port, app.get('env'));
});
```

And when run gives:

2017-09-16T17:07:18-0400  app.js:192 (Server.) Express server listening on 9000, in production mode
AND everything works except for the 404's for socket.io POST's

Comment: Please post the nginx logs showing the reason for 404

Comment: Okay - thanks... I will add the log at the end of the question.... in a few...

Comment: NATURALLY, since I wanted to rotate all my logs and produce a clean set of logs, I rebooted the server (on Digital Ocean) and now all the issues with 404 have vanished.   Go Figure!!  But the good news is that I couldn't find anything wrong with my config, because there apparently anything wrong. But thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830850/tarun-lalwani for looking at this!!!!

Comment: Hi Joel. Would you post an answer below (as an answer proper rather than a comment)? We don't use [solved] title edits here, nor add answers to titles. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue came from some unknown on the server.  Simply restarting the droplet on DigitalOcean took care of the problem.